# Layout Preview not working in android studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Recently my android studio not displaying designs in preview

Tried :

- Rebuilded application
- invalidate cache and restarted
- restarted system too

I'm getting below exception in log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@7f378372
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor513.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.callMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:108)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder_Delegate.java:143)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.nCallFloatMethod(PropertyValuesHolder.java)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder.access$400(PropertyValuesHolder.java:38)
    at android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder$FloatPropertyValuesHolder.setAnimatedValue(PropertyValuesHolder.java:1387)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.animateValue(ObjectAnimator.java:990)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentFraction(ValueAnimator.java:674)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(ValueAnimator.java:637)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1069)
    at android.animation.ValueAnimator.start(ValueAnimator.java:1088)
    at android.animation.ObjectAnimator.start(ObjectAnimator.java:852)
    at android.animation.StateListAnimator.start(StateListAnimator.java:188)
    at android.animation.StateListAnimator.setState(StateListAnimator.java:181)
    at android.view.View.drawableStateChanged(View.java:21105)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawableStateChanged(ViewGroup.java:7101)
    at com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.drawableStateChanged(AppBarLayout.java:393)
    at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:21160)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18379)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:42)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:335)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:391)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:540)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:666)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note : It's working fine before

Gradle Dependencies are

```
dependencies { configuration ->
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    androidSupport(configuration)
    customViews(configuration)
    def parceler_verion = '1.1.12'
    implementation 'com.batch.android:batch-sdk:1.13.0'
    implementation "org.parceler:parceler-api:$parceler_verion"
    annotationProcessor "org.parceler:parceler:$parceler_verion"
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.3'
    implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:8.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    test(configuration)
    network(configuration)
    googleAndFirebase(configuration)
    rxJava(configuration)
    driveQuantSDK(configuration)
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${kotlin_version}"
}

private static void test(configuration) {
    configuration.testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    configuration.androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    configuration.androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    configuration.implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.0'
}

private static void androidSupport(configuration) {

    configuration.implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
    configuration.implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    configuration.implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
}

private static void customViews(configuration) {
    configuration.implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3'
    configuration.implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    configuration.implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.2'
    configuration.implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.3.0'
    configuration.implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:2.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:rximagepicker:2.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.0'
}

private static void network(configuration) {
    def retrofit_version = '2.4.0'
    def glide_version = '4.8.0'
    def okhttp_logging_version = '3.10.0'
    def stetho_version = '1.5.0'

    configuration.implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_logging_version"
    configuration.implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    configuration.implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    configuration.implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit_version"
    configuration.implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    configuration.implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:$stetho_version"
    configuration.implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:$stetho_version"


}

private static void googleAndFirebase(configuration) {
    //gcm
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'

    //Firebase libs
//    configuration.implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

    //lib for map
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    //google analytics
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6'

    //map utils
    configuration.implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
}

private static void rxJava(configuration) {
    def rxjava_version = '2.1.12'
    def rxjava_android_version = '2.0.2'
    configuration.implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxjava_version"
    configuration.implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxjava_android_version"
}
```

Comment: You have a class cast exception somewhere in your code not allowing you to rebuild the project and thus previews are temporarily broken.

Comment: @Roger it's already worked .now only not worked.

Comment: @PFuster do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: Are you using any custom made Views?

Comment: @RajasekaranM it is very difficult to fix a problem, when all you can see is a fraction of it. You will need to add to your question a bunch of things, e.g.: does your android studio work fine if you create a new project? Does "Main Activity" show fine? (the default layout for a single activity template), etc. This alone doesn't say much about what could be happening, something you already figured out, and that's why you're posting the question here :)

Comment: @PFuster no. I used constraint layout,appbar,toolbar and recyclerview

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I checked many layout files from my application .no one showing preview but it's working fine before

Comment: When you hit re-build can you post all the logs that are outputted

Comment: @RajasekaranM Well, I'm glad you checked many layout files! But we haven't because we don't have them. Does your Android Studio work with another project? Does this ONLY happen with your application? If the answer is YES to either or both, then you will clearly need to show more about your project.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini thanks for your help. actually issue with `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout` but I don't know why it's happened for me? My layout showing after removing appbar from layout

Comment: and what did you change before/after this happened? Did you open Android Studio today and it was failing without you changing anything?

Comment: Android studio is running from morning in my system, And my layout still not showing with AppBarLayout but it's showing before.

Comment: yes I removed AppBarLayout from my layout.xml file

Comment: Can you post your Gradle dependencies? It might be due to androidx and app compat library issues.

Comment: @PFuster I have added gradle dependencies.. sry for later reply

Comment: @RajasekaranM For me it was circle image view, It didn't worked with new material library. If you have used CIV in your layout replace it with normal ImageView and try to build and see if it works or not.

Comment: yes , I'm also having CIV in my layout

Comment: I wonder if it's a conflict between the new material library and any of the custom view dependencies. Can you try removing the custom view dependencies one by one to see which one is the culprit?

Comment: now for me working for with CIV and without CIV

Answer (score 1):

Inside your preview Change the `Theme`

[image]

That may solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06' downgrade it to 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'